# Limited size in grid view column(truncate string length)

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

This is My grid view coding i want menu name truncate length baseed.

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="MenuName" HeaderText="MenuName" TruncateLegnth="6" />
 <asp:BoundField DataField="Url" HeaderText="Url" />
  <asp:BoundField DataField="Tooltip" HeaderText="Tooltip" />
```

Previously i am using dynamic value set

protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            int i = 0;

```
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            foreach (TableCell cell in e.Row.Cells)
            {
                i++;
                string Word = cell.Text;


                if (cell.Text.Length > 5 && (i == 1))
                    cell.Text = cell.Text.Substring(0, 5) + "....";

                if (cell.Text.Length > 3 && (i == 3))
                    cell.Text = cell.Text.Substring(0, 3) + "....";
                if (cell.Text.Length > 6 && (i == 2))
                    cell.Text = cell.Text.Substring(0, 6) + "....";
                cell.ToolTip = Word;
            }
        }


    }
```

Now i need TruncateLegnth based column.

Answer (score 0):

Why to not give your cell a css class with text overflow property set to ellipsis?

```
.cell {
    white-space: nowrap; 
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis; 
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_text-overflow